# JavaxException Unknown SMTP host Exception: mail.gmail.com

Tags: java, jsp, ide

I am trying to send mail using Java code . The code is working fine when running on my personal PC . But on office network the exception of unknown SMTP host is appearing. Also my office pc is not able to ping smtp.gmail.com. PC firewall is closed as well.
Is there any other way to establish the connection?  I am also providing my code below for reference.

```
mport javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;

public class otp {    
    String d_email = "email@gmail.com",
            d_password = "password",
            d_uname="uname",//your email password
            d_host = "mail.outlook.com",
            d_port = "587",
            m_to = "target@gmail.com", // Target email address
            m_subject = "Testing Mail programs",
            m_text = "Hey, this is a test email.";

    public otp() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        try {
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,auth); 
            session.setDebug(true);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(m_text);
            msg.setSubject(m_subject);
            System.out.println(1);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));

            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to));

            System.out.println(3);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(d_host, Integer.valueOf(d_port),d_uname , d_password);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Message Sent succesfully");  
      } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        otp blah = new otp();
    }

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
     public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(d_email, d_password);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are behind the internal firewall/proxy of your office, it is very common to put the whole internal network of a company behind a central firewall or to check Outgoing/Incoming requests of the networks traffic a Dynamic Proxy Server.in that case, you can check it in the proxy settings of your pc.
internet explorer(or any browser)-> settings -> internet option ->  Connections Tab -> LAN Settings.

for the granular analyses,please attach your code.

Comment: i tried to disable the proxy still iasm facing the same  error message of Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;

Comment: normally you cannot easily disable a dynamic-proxy on your local pc,basically such a system configuration is managed by system admin

Answer (score 0):

you are using a gmail account but you have provided a outlook host , try the following template:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmailUsingGMailSMTP {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "xyz@gmail.com";//change accordingly

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "abc@gmail.com";//change accordingly
      final String username = "abc";//change accordingly
      final String password = "*****";//change accordingly

      // >> gmail host
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

      // Get the Session object.
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
         }
      });

      try {
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
         InternetAddress.parse(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("Hello, this is sample for to check send "
            + "email using JavaMailAPI ");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);

         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

      } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }enter code here
   }
}
```